# Linear Algebraic question

Tags: matrices

A degree-2 polynomial curve reads $p(x)=C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2$ and you are told that three samples of the $(x,p(x))$-tuple are $(1,2), (2,9)$ and $(3,22)$.Find the coefficients $C_0,C_1$ and $C_2$. Then, determine if $(-1,5)$ falls on the curve.

Answer (score 1):

We have here, three systems of linear equations by substituting the three values of $x \in$ {$1,2,3$}. $$C_0 + C_1 + C_2 =2$$ $$C_0 + 2C_1 + 4C_2 = 9$$ $$C_0 + 3C_1 + 9C_2 = 22$$. We can solve this by using many methods such as matrix and row reduction or by just manipulating the equations by adding and subtracting the. Thus, we have $C_0 = 1, C_1 =-2, C_2 =3$. Hence our polynomial is $p(x) = 3x^2-2x+1$.

It can be found that $p(-1) =6\neq 5$, so $(-1,5)$ does not lie on $p(x)$.